# Should I use Canonical Tag ? I have replaced underscore by hyphen in url

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url, rel-canonical, codeigniter

I have created a website in codeigniter. Some urls have underscore eg:demo.com/heritagehome_cochin . so I replaced underscore with hyphen for seo friendy URL by changing routes.php file.

My doubt is should I use the Canonical Tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Canonical Tag and Google can pickup it automatically.

Comment: Can you give a link to information about this?

Comment: Sorry, there is no specific article about it for codeigniter but you can ask to John Mueller on Twitter.